# How can I do or operator(number a | number b) in MariaDB (InnoDB Engine)?

Tags: mariadb, bit-manipulation, innodb

I tried to do **or** operator (aka |) in MariaDB (InnoDB Engine).
When I tried or operator with negative number, I got a wrong result.

Ex) SELECT -1107296257 | -8388608 => result : 18446744073709551615

Does MariaDB use 1's complement or someting else (except 2's complement)?

If they use other, how can I set 2's complement in MariaDB.

Thanks

Comment: Looks correct to me. Note that "all [bitwise operations] return a result of the BIGINT UNSIGNED type". MariaDB uses 2's complement.

Comment: What is the general case?  That is, where did those numbers come form and why do you want to bitwise OR them together?

Comment: InnoDB doesn't perform this maths, its in a shared implementation above the storage layer.